# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow - Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

Hi I am getting the following error when computing GMT Time using nanoseconds as a long.

**System.OverflowException**: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.'

Is there another data type that would work better with big values?

```
Private Sub gmtime(ByVal iSeconds As Object, ByVal iNanoseconds As Long, ByRef Timestamp As String)

    Dim time As Object
    Dim islpyr, lpcnt As Long
    Dim t As Object
    Dim i As Object
    Dim ystart As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim sph As Object  'seconds per hour
    Dim spd As Object  'seconds per day
    Dim spy As Object  'seconds per year
    Dim tm_sec As Long
    Dim tm_min As Long
    Dim tm_hour As Long
    Dim tm_mday As Long
    Dim tm_mon As Long
    Dim tm_year As Long
    Dim tm_wday As Long
    Dim tm_yday As Long
    Dim tm_isdst As Long
    Dim mons(11) As Long
    Dim temp As Object
    Dim iMicroSeconds As Long
    Dim iZeroCount As Long
    Dim strZero As String
    Dim strMicro As String
    Dim iMicroData As Long

    mons(0) = 31
    mons(1) = 28
    mons(2) = 31
    mons(3) = 30
    mons(4) = 31
    mons(5) = 30
    mons(6) = 31
    mons(7) = 31
    mons(8) = 30
    mons(9) = 31
    mons(10) = 30
    mons(11) = 31

    sph = CDec(60 * 60)
    spd = CDec(24 * sph)
    spy = CDec(365 * spd + 6 * sph)   'a year is about 365.25 days

    tm_isdst = 0

    time = CDec(iSeconds)
    If time < 0 Then
        time = time * (-1)
    End If
    i = CDec(time)
    i = Fix(i / spd) Mod 7 + 4
    While i >= 7
        i = i - 7
    End While
    tm_wday = i
    temp = Fix(time / spd)
    temp = temp * spd
    i = time - temp
    tm_hour = Fix(i / sph) Mod 24
    tm_min = Fix(i / 60) Mod 60
    tm_sec = i Mod 60

    y = Fix(time / spy)
    y = y + 370
    time = Fix(time / spd)

    Do
        islpyr = 0
        If ((y Mod 4) = 0) And (((y Mod 100) <> 0) Or ((y Mod 400) = 0)) Then
            islpyr = 1
        End If
        lpcnt = Fix(y / 4)
        lpcnt = lpcnt - Fix(y / 100)
        lpcnt = lpcnt + Fix(y / 400)

        lpcnt = lpcnt - 89
        ystart = (y - 370) * 365 + lpcnt
        If ystart > time Then
            y = y - 1
        End If

    Loop While ystart > time

    time = time - ystart

    If time = 365 Then
        time = 0
        y = y + 1
    End If

    If islpyr Then
        time = time + 1
    End If
    tm_yday = time
    time = time + 1

    For i = 0 To 10
        t = mons(i)
        If (i = 1) And (islpyr = 1) Then
            t = t + 1
        End If
        If time <= t Then
            Exit For
        End If
        time = time - t
    Next i

    tm_year = y - 300 + 1900
    tm_mon = i + 1
    tm_mday = time

    strZero = "."
    iZeroCount = 6
    iMicroSeconds = Fix(iNanoseconds / 1000)
    iMicroData = iMicroSeconds
    While iMicroSeconds <> 0
        iMicroSeconds = Fix(iMicroSeconds / 10)
        If (iMicroData Mod 10) = 0 Then
            iMicroData = iMicroSeconds
        End If
        If iZeroCount <> 0 Then
            iZeroCount = iZeroCount - 1
        End If
    End While

    For i = 1 To iZeroCount
        strZero = strZero + "0"
    Next i

    If Fix(iNanoseconds / 1000) <> 0 Then
        strMicro = strZero + CStr(Fix(iNanoseconds / 1000))
    Else
        strMicro = strZero
    End If

    Timestamp = CStr(tm_year) + "-" + CStr(tm_mon) + "-" + CStr(tm_mday) + " " + CStr(tm_hour) + ":" + CStr(tm_min) + ":" + CStr(tm_sec) + strMicro

End Sub
```

It wouldn't let me add the code as the post is mostly code. The nanoseconds values are coming from a waveform file and this function is used to process it into GMT time.

The function is called on a loop for each line of the file and returns this error mid-way through the loop.

The value is '**1.5518651852110167E+270**' when it hits the error

Comment: Please show the relevant code that's producing the error.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Sorry it wouldn't let me add the code as it ws much larger that the content. I have added it now.

Comment: @video.baba I've changed it now

Comment: Can you explain what this means: "The nanoseconds values are coming from a waveform file"

Comment: @video.baba I'm reading a file line by line. One of the values on each line is a nanoseconds value representing the date and time that line was created

Comment: The code above has nothing to do with reading values from a file. So you are getting a nanoseconds value, from a file, then what? What do you want to do with that? Represent that value as a time? (I'm getting confused by all the declarations and code in your example above in relation to your question).

Comment: @video.baba is simple, He wants to put "1.5518651852110167E+270" inside a long.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: If the timestamp is zero at January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar then if you drop the last two characters of `TimeStamp` and convert it to an Int64 (a.k.a. Long) then you can use the [DateTime(Int64) constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2). And pop the two dropped characters on the end of the DateTime.ToString value if you want.

Comment: @AndrewMorton to store `1.5518651852110167E+270` as he said you need 897 bytes lol

Comment: @Simo I think it is more likely that there is a bug which is generating such a large value than that the OP actually has a use for a number that large.

Comment: @AndrewMorton we cannot know it, becasue the PO didn't give us enough informations.

Comment: Thanks for the replys. I think there is most likely an error in the way the data is being read in. The function works in VBA but not VB so I'm going to delve further into the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but there's no way to put a `10^270` number inside **ANY** variable.

The biggest variable for numbers is `Long` that holds:

> signed 64-bit (8-byte) integers ranging in value from
>   `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` through `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`
>   (9.2...**E+18**).

From [Long DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type)

I sueggest you to avoiding counting time in ***nanoseconds*** instead use seconds, minutes, or even days if your `TimeSpan` is too big.

Counting time in nanoseconds is pointless.

***Remarks***

If you couldn't avoid using nanoseconds because your file is in nanoseconds your only option is to convert you nanoseconds value in a DateTime format on every line and hope that the value will be shorter than **9.2E+18**

Otherwise you could use a [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) and use it to calculate a `DateTime` for every line of your file.

Just for the curiosity: You would need a `896 bytes unsigned DataType` to store a `1.5*10^270` inside it.

Comment: I don't think we can get any further with this without some more info/response from the OP. We could break things down into multiple variables. I just get a feeling there's far too much code than needs to be there........

Comment: @video.baba yes, clearly too much useless code for us.
But the problem is well described in the last PO's sentences.

Comment: @video.baba i cannot understand if he just doesn't know the range value of a `long` data type or if he's just trolling...

Comment: lol, I understand. But my curiosity is getting the better of me ;-)

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for the suggestion, but if a single line is so big (I mean 1.55E+270) i don't think that a BigInteger will be capable of that.

Comment: @Simo `Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Log10(BigInteger.Parse(New String("1"c, 1000))))` outputs 999.06 (approx.).

Comment: @simo Thanks for the reply. I think there is most likely an error in the way the data is being read in. The function works in VBA but not VB so I'm going to delve further into the issue.

Comment: Tell us if you'll come out with something